# How would I invoke PowerShell w32tm resync command using C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to invoke w32tm resync on a remote device and determine if it was successful.  Here is what I am trying now with no luck.  Is there an obvious mistake in my code ?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //// use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
            //// use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.

            //Create password variable
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"mypassword\" -AsPlainText -Force;");

            //Create Credential Object
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (\"mycomputer\\Administrator\",$password);");
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName minwinpc -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {w32tm /resync /force;}");

            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                if (outputItem != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName);
                    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
```